# Navigate to other page upon button click in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three files Login.js , LoginValidation.js and App.js. In Login.js i used arrow fucntion with props.In LoginValidation.js ,i imported Login.js. In LoginValidation i used class and component. In the state i declared four variables . two for updating the state and two values are default values of username and password where i will validate with the first two variables later.with onchange event i have captured the values of username and password and updated the state of first two variables. Later I validated the captured values with the default values in the state ,if matches i will navigate to some other page.

//Login .js file

```
const login=(props)=>{

 return(
    <div class="login">
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
     <form >
     <label >Username: </label>
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" onChange={props.username}/>
     <br></br> <br></br>
     <label>Password:  </label>
     <input type="password" name="passwd"  placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={props.passwd} />

      <br></br> <br></br>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.click}>Login</button>

      </form>
    </div>

 )};
export default login;
```

//LoginValidation.js file

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
class LoginValidation extends Component{
state={
    username:'',
    password:'',
    uname:'dddddd',
    pwd:'22222'
};
```

//Function to capture the inputs and to update the state

```
changeHandler=(event)=>{
    if(event.target.name==="username"){
        this.setState({username:event.target.value});
    }
    if(event.target.name==="password"){
        this.setState({username:event.target.value});
    }
};
```

//Function execute upon button click

```
clickHandler=(state)=>{
    const uname=this.state.uname;
    const pwd=this.state.pwd;
    if(this.state.username===uname && this.state.password===pwd){
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
    else{
        alert("Enter proper Credentials")
    }
}

render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <Login username={this.changeHandler} password={this.changeHandler} 
            click={this.clickHandler}
          />

      </div>
    )
}


}
export default withRouter(LoginValidation);
```

I went somewhere wrong upon button click unable to figure it out.  can you please help me ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the current error or behavior when button is clicked?

Comment: I am unable to redirect to the page what i had given

Comment: are there error when you inspect your console?

Comment: I didnt found any error in my console

Answer (score 0):

In Your changeHandler you setState to username 2 times instead of password

```
  changeHandler=(event)=>{
        if(event.target.name==="username"){
            this.setState({username:event.target.value});
        }
        if(event.target.name==="password"){
            this.setState({username:event.target.value});
        }
    };
```

A better way to handle changes in react is:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
   this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
   })
}
```

Just pass the state property you want to update has parameter like `handleChange(username)`

Also, in your `Login.js` you have this:

```
<input type="password" name="passwd"  placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={props.passwd} />
```

If you pass it as `password` you should use `props.password`